# Grouping Elements on Conditions in Penthao Report Designer

Tags: sql, pentaho, report-designer

I want to make a Report in Penthao Report Designer

My SQL query tells me the SUM of some variables and another variable is already the same SUM. 
So for Example

```
DATE Name Expected SUM
Today A    20       20
Today B    10        5
```

Inside the Report Designer i select a Text field which is OK if Expected-SUM=0 else Error.
Inside my Report i know want to display if for "Today" all those Textfields are OK (than one row should display OK) or if at least one of them is Error than only Display one Row with Error for a given Date

I'm thankfull for every suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

As here are no suggestions so far, maybe this is one solution: I would do this with an JavaScript-Step, but as a tranformation with a field and a filter-step:

Javascript:

```
var testing = "";
if(expected - sum == 0){
testing = "ok";
}
else {
testing = date;
}
```

And after that a filter-step, which sends rows to an "error"-output-report (with given date): filter is "testing NOT ok".

Sorry if thats not the solution for your problem, I have no experiences with Reports ... But maybe it's a hint and you asked for "every suggestion" :)
Hope it works!